# How to Compare Dates In Firestore Rules From Database And Request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Recently I Was Working On A Platform Where I Came Across A Problem Where I Want To Compare A Timestamp Stored In The Users Database And The Time Of Request In Firebase Rules. This Is So That One Can Read The Document Only If He/She Requests Only After A Certain Time.
Here Are The Codes I Tried To Use So Far.
Note: The Fieldname `strton` refers to a Time Stamp Object In The Document Of The Database.

```
match /tests/{testsID}{
   match /response/{responseID}{
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tests/{testID}).data.strton < request.time;
      }
}
```

```
match /tests/{testsID}{
  match /response/{responseID}{
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tests/{testID}).data.strton.toMillis() < request.time.toMillis();
      }
}
```

Any Help On How I Can Achieve This Is Appreciated.

Updates:
Here's The Document Structure(Private Info Has Been Censored)
[image: Firebase Screenshot]
And The Code Which Is Trying To Access It

```
docRef = doc(db, "tests", testid,"responses",auth.currentUser.uid);
  docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    testResponseList = docSnap.data()
  }else {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "tests", testid,"responses",auth.currentUser.uid), {
      answers:[]})
```

One More Thing Is That The Document Which This Code Is Trying To Get Doesnt Exist Right Now. And The Else Statement Is For Making The Document If It doesnt Exist. But the else statement is not executed.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the app code making the request.  Security rules alone don't mean much unless they are paired with queries they are specifically trying to allow.

Comment: Im sorry. I was used to typing this way. The app code is just a `getDoc` request in Javascript.

Comment: Can you share the `getDoc(<the_doc_id>)` code and also a screenshot of that document being fetched so it can be checked if there's any issue with data in doc?

Comment: The additional details you needed i have added it.

Comment: The Else Statement isnt Executed because the await GetDoc function itself is returning the error `Missing or insufficient permissions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `{wildcard}` expression syntax that is used in document path with `/match` in `get()`. Instead you should be using `$(testsID)`.

Also there are a few spelling errors:

- Your collection name is `responses` but you have `response` in rules
- It is `testsID` in wilcard but you have `testID`

Try refactoring the rules as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /tests/{testID} {
      match /responses/{responseID} {
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tests/$(testID)).data.strton < request.time;
      }
    }   
  }
}
```